# "This app does not have access to your photos and video" in iOS 9.1

Tags: swift, ios9.1

I have a single page application where user can tap on the image and `ImagePickerController` shows up for the use to pick image from camera roll.

The same code when included in much larger project based on Tab View controller, I get the error "This app does not have access to your photos and video".

also I tried to include "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" in `info.plist` but no luck. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your privacy settings in Apple Settings > Privacy > Photos?  iOS should ask for permission on first use.  If the user declines, all you can do is tell the user to go to settings and allow access.  I'm guessing this Setting is OFF for you.

You can check for authorization status in the app.  I program in Objective C, and I'm using an iOS 8+ only class PHPhotoLibrary, but maybe the code below will give you some ideas.  (There's some "ShowMessage" psuedo code also.)

```
- (void) loadView {
    [self continueWithStatus: [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]];
}

- (void) continueWithStatus: (PHAuthorizationStatus) status {

    if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted)  ShowMessage "Access to photo library is restricted.";  
    else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusDenied) ShowMessage "You need to enable access to photos.  Apple Settings > Privacy > Photos.";
    else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization: ^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
            dispatch_async (dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{   // continue work on main thread
                [self continueWithStatus: [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus]];
            });
        }];
    }
    else [self startAssetRetrieve];
}
```

---

Thanks for your guidance. I used the above logic and created following swift code:

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender:
 UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    authHandler(PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()) 
}
func authHandler(status: PHAuthorizationStatus) {
    switch status {
    case .Authorized:
        startAssetRevrival()
    case .Denied:
        print("denied")
    case .NotDetermined:
        print("not determined")
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(f)
    case .Restricted:
        print("restricted")
    }
  }
  func f(status: PHAuthorizationStatus){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.authHandler(status)
    }
 }

 func startAssetRevrival() {
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = 
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an
       image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true,
    completion: nil)
}
```

Now I see that status starts with Not Determined and then to Denied. In the Privacy Setting, I don't see name of my application listed.

Comment: I ended up recreating the project in Xcode. Images are picked up as expected.